# How can I get a subentry in moderncv?

Tags: moderncv

In my cv, I want my internship to be a sub-entry of my masters education.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}

\firstname{Ice}
\familyname{Rabbit}
\title{curriculum vitae}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\makecvtitle
\end{center}

\section{Education}
\cventry{2011 -- 2014}{Master Penguin science}{University of Queen Maud Land}{Antarctica}{}{More learning about penguin behaviour in Antarctica.}

\cventry{2012}{Internship}{University of Ellesmere Island}{Nunavut, Canada}{}{Internship assignment. The goal was to find penguins in the Canadian Arctic.}

\cventry{2006 -- 2011}{Bachelor Penguin science}{University of Queen Maud Land}{Antarctica}{}{Learning about penguin behaviour.}

\end{document}
```

Result
[image: MWE result]

I've gotten the advice to indent the internship entry, to make it more clear that it was a part of my masters education, rather than a separate education.

How can I indent this entry? Alternatively, is there another method to clearly list my internship as part of my masters education? I do want the internship to be clearly present, since on my real cv it shows some good achievements (international experience, high grade, scientific publication)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a new command `\subcventry` and use it instead of `\cventry` when you want it indented:

```
\newcommand*{\subcventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\hspace*{1em}\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    .\strut%
    \ifx&#7&%
      \else{\newline{}\hspace*{1em}\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-1em}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}
```

Note that if you want to adjust the indentation, you have to modify `1em`, which occurs three times in the definition.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}

\firstname{Ice}
\familyname{Rabbit}
\title{curriculum vitae}

\newcommand*{\subcventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\hspace*{1em}\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    .\strut%
    \ifx&#7&%
      \else{\newline{}\hspace*{1em}\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-1em}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\makecvtitle
\end{center}

\section{Education}
\cventry{2011 -- 2014}{Master Penguin science}{University of Queen Maud Land}{Antarctica}{}{More learning about penguin behaviour in Antarctica.}

\subcventry{2012}{Internship}{University of Ellesmere Island}{Nunavut, Canada}{}{Internship assignment. The goal was to find penguins in the Canadian Arctic.}

\cventry{2006 -- 2011}{Bachelor Penguin science}{University of Queen Maud Land}{Antarctica}{}{Learning about penguin behaviour.}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I've combined your solution with a `\vspace{4mm}` between the internship and bachelor entry, which makes for a very clear distinction between master/internship and bachelor.

Comment: @IceRabbit You're welcome. Happy to help. :-)

Answer (score 3):

If `cvline` and `enumitem` are allowed, this is an alternative where a customized macro `\ccvline` taking 4 parameters (year, title/job, school, description) is defined.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\firstname{Ice}
\familyname{Rabbit}
\title{curriculum vitae}

\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*,align=left,nosep,labelsep=0.5cm}

\newcommand*{\ccvline}[4]{
\cvline{#1}{
\vspace{-3mm}
\begin{itemize}[label=$$]
\item  {\bfseries #2} {\slshape #3} {\small #4}
\end{itemize}
\vspace{-3mm}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\makecvtitle
\end{center}

\section{Education}
\cventry{2011 -- 2014}{Master Penguin science}{University of Queen Maud Land}{Antarctica}{}{More learning about penguin behaviour in Antarctica.}
\ccvline{2012}{Internship}{University of Ellesmere Island, Nunavut, Canada.\newline}{Internship assignment. The goal was to find penguins in the Canadian Arctic.}
\cventry{2006 -- 2011}{Bachelor Penguin science}{University of Queen Maud Land}{Antarctica}{}{Learning about penguin behaviour.}

\end{document}
```