# Moderncv subentry with indented wrapping text

Tags: indentation, moderncv

[How can I get a subentry in moderncv?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161628/how-can-i-get-a-subentry-in-moderncv/)

I've implemented the solution in the above post, but I was wondering if there is some easy way to allow the indentation to also work for wrapped text? So that the entire block gets indented, not just the first line.

MEW:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{classic}

\newcommand*{\subcventry}[7][.25em]{%
    \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
        {\hspace*{1em}#3}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
        .\strut%
        \ifx&#7&%
        \else{\newline{}\hspace*{1em}\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-1em}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi
    }
}

\firstname{Mr.}
\familyname{Awesome} 

\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{2.6cm}

\begin{document}
\section{Experience}

\cventry{November 2007 -- current}{Mr. Awesome}{Awesome Ltd.}{The Earth}{}{}
\subcventry{July 2015}{Intake of Awesomeness version 2}{}{}{}{}
\subcventry{May 2014 -- current}{SPOC for all awesomeness in all our awesome clients, which includes Awesome1, Awesome2, awesome3 and awesome4}{}{}{}{}
\end{document}
```

So I want to fully ident the SPOC line, both lines of it.

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of your used command `\subcventry` does only allow to have more than one line in argument `#7`, inserted in an own `minipage`.

You can test this with the example command

```
\subcventry{November 2007 -- current--2}{Mr. Awesome--3}{Awesome Ltd.--4}{The Earth--5}{test--6}{test--7}
```

The compilable MWE shows you a correct layout if you move your long text into the last argument:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{classic}

\newcommand*{\subcventry}[7][.25em]{%
    \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
        {\hspace*{1em}#3}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
        .\strut%
        \ifx&#7&%
        \else{\newline{}\hspace*{1em}\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-1em}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi
    }
}

\firstname{Mr.}
\familyname{Awesome} 

\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{2.6cm}

\begin{document}
\section{Experience}

\cventry{November 2007 -- current}{Mr. Awesome}{Awesome Ltd.}{The Earth}{}{}
\subcventry{November 2007 -- current--2}{Mr. Awesome--3}{Awesome Ltd.--4}{The Earth--5}{test--6}{test--7}
\subcventry{July 2015}{Intake of Awesomeness version 2}{}{}{}{}
\subcventry{May 2014 -- current}{SPOC}{}{}{}{SPOC for all awesomeness in all our awesome clients, which includes Awesome1, Awesome2, awesome3 and awesome4}
\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image]

The last `\subcventry` shows the result with moved argument ...

Or you can define a new own command `\mysubcventry` like

```
\newcommand*{\mysubcventry}[3][.25em]{%
    \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
        {\hspace*{1em}\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-1em}\small#3\end{minipage}}
    }
}
```

with two parameters and one option (for the vertical space at the end of command `\cvitem`).

With the following MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{classic}

\newcommand*{\subcventry}[7][.25em]{%
    \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
        {\hspace*{1em}#3}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
        .\strut%
        \ifx&#7&%
        \else{\newline{}\hspace*{1em}\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-1em}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi
    }
}

\newcommand*{\mysubcventry}[3][.25em]{%
    \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
        {\hspace*{1em}\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-1em}\small#3\end{minipage}}
    }
}

\firstname{Mr.}
\familyname{Awesome} 

\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{2.6cm}


\begin{document}
\section{Experience}

\cventry{November 2007 -- current}{Mr. Awesome}{Awesome Ltd.}{The Earth}{}{}
\subcventry{November 2007 -- current--2}{Mr. Awesome--3}{Awesome Ltd.--4}{The Earth--5}{test--6}{test--7.}
\subcventry{July 2015}{Intake of Awesomeness version 2}{}{}{}{}
\subcventry{May 2014 -- current}{SPOC}{}{}{}{SPOC for all awesomeness in all our awesome clients, which includes Awesome1, Awesome2, awesome3 and awesome4.}
\mysubcventry[5em]{May 2014 -- current}{SPOC for all awesomeness in all our awesome clients, which includes Awesome1, Awesome2, awesome3 and awesome4.}
\mysubcventry{May 2014 -- current}{SPOC for all awesomeness in all our awesome clients, which includes Awesome1, Awesome2, awesome3 and awesome4.}
\end{document}
```

you get the result

[image]

Comment: Ok, while this solution didn't really provide what I was looking for, it did helped me how to interprete the newcommand that was being defined.

For my own uses, I've redefined it as:

````\newcommand*{\subcventry}[3][.25em]{

 \cvitem[#1]{#2}{  \hspace*{1em} \begin{minipage}[t] { \dimexpr \linewidth-1em} \small#3 \end{minipage}}

}
````