# Moderncv subentry with indented multiline text

Tags: moderncv, renewcommand

I want to add some kind of subentry related to, e.g., a project within a work position. I came across a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161628/how-can-i-get-a-subentry-in-moderncv/) whose answer I tried to solve my problem. However, if the bold entry exceeds the line width and a new line is created, the 2nd line is no longer indented.

Example:

```
\subcventry{}{This is a very long title that goes over several lines and is no longer indented correctly}{}{}{}{}
```

In the definition of the command, `\hspace*` is already used. The only solution I can think of is manually breaking the line and inserting a new `\hspace*` manually. For instance:

```
\subcventry{}{This is a very long title that goes over several lines and is no longer\newline{}\hspace*{1em}indented correctly}{}{}{}{}
```

However, I am looking for a more elegant solution to fix the problem within the definition of the `\subcventry` command. I am glad for any suggestions.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/402126/161015